# Sleeping aside me

Tags: word-choice

My friend used this sentence:

> I wouldn’t be able to sleep at nights if she is sleeping *aside* me.

Is the usage of the word *aside* correct here? I always thought “sleeping *besides* me” is the right way.

Please help me understand.

Comment: *Besides* means "apart from, in addition to". The word for "next to" is *beside*.

Comment: As an aside, this question has me beside myself.

Comment: Off topic: critique request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither *aside me* nor *besides me* is correct.  The first is ungrammatical, and the second one means something else: it means “other than me”.

You must use *beside me* if you mean that she sleeps by your side.

Comment: Although there do seem to be some historical occurrences of aside used this way, I agree that beside is the only acceptable one now.

Comment: If it meant anything, ? *she was sleeping besides me* would mean 'as well as me'.

Comment: @Rory what's more, Wiktionary lists *besides* with the meaning "beside", [as "obsolete"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besides) yet meaning number one. I wonder where they got if from — no other dictionary I have checked this far does that. Though Shakespeare Search does turn up [a couple cites](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/ss.cgi?q=besides&mode=k) that seem relevant.

Answer (score 5):

*[Aside](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside)* and *[beside](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beside)* have nearly the same core meaning, i.e. "to one side of", but they are different parts of speech: *aside* is an adverb, *beside* is a preposition.  In Standard Written English, the construction 'she was [action]ing [relative location] me' requires you to use a preposition to express the [relative location].  Thus, if you use *aside* here, that is formally incorrect.  To a native speaker, this particular incorrectness will sound archaic rather than flat-out wrong, therefore it *can* be used deliberately for effect.  However, deliberate archaism is a difficult effect to achieve successfully in English: even stylists of great skill ([E. R. Eddison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_R%C3%BCcker_Eddison) comes to mind) have had it fall flat on them.

[*Besides*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/besides) is a related but different word, which means "in addition to" or "other than".  It is not formally incorrect to say "she was sleeping besides me", but it doesn't mean what your friend wanted to say, and it is not the most natural way to say what it does mean (in context, I would probably say "I wouldn't be able to sleep at night (if/unless) she were asleep too").

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED, *aside* means *to one side; out of the way:*

> *he pushed his plate aside | they stood aside to let a car pass | she must put aside all her antagonistic feelings.*

*Besides* on the other hand means *in addition to; apart from*. So that doesn't seem to be the word you are looking for.

> *I have no other family besides my parents*.

I think the word you are looking for, as others have mentioned, is *beside* which means *next to; at the side of*:

> *She sat beside my at the front seat.*

Note: Some dictionaries register beside to mean both *in addition to* and *next to*. So you can use *beside* to mean both *beside* and *besides* but not the other way around.